# Is there TOP VIEW(or window) on xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms.

I wanted to know if there is top window or view for Xamarin.forms. 
I want to put something like a alert or indicator so that it remain on top depth all the time until it's gone. (even if new page is pushed.)

I can't find any view or window on XF.
Should I use each native window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert` method to display alert from the MainPage (which ordinary always exists in app).

Comment: Thanks. Taras. It seems like that there is no guarantee that view is always top(I know it's top when it's called but if new page is pushed some reason, it could not be still top). But it's good to know.

Comment: In fact, you can display alert even when not MainPage is on the screen. It looks like `DisplayAlert` method pushing Alert Page modal, so it will overlap any current page on the screen. I've just tried it in my app, when I was not on my MainPage and it works. Maybe also that's because my MainPage is NavigationPage, so I always have my MainPage on the screen. In any case, try it out, maybe it will work just fine for you)

Comment: DisplayAlert calls native alert view. Of course it should be always top. That's not what I want. I mentioned Alert  just for example. It could be some image or something in my case.

Comment: I have to cancel my first comment. I didn't look correctly and thought Oh, there is something I don't know. but what you mentioned was DIsplayAlert method, which calls native alert view. I'm sorry that I didn't look carefully. That's not what I want.

Comment: In that case you can use `GlobalNavigation` with `PushModalAsync` method, like in [this documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xamarin.forms/1571/navigation-in-xamarin-forms-navigationpages-vs-modal/5549/navigationpage-flow-with-xaml#t=201608021945071280628)

Comment: If you don't mind, I would like to make sure if we are talking about same issue. I want to access most top window to attach my view on it. I'm not asking how to call alertview nor call new modal page. Thanks.